# Capturing an image with ngx-webcam and sending it to face recognition api

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, base64

I am currently trying to directly send an image via ngx-webcam without saving it to my backend server and send it to a [Face Detection API](https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection?endpoint=53aa3243e4b07e1f4ebe9bb3) via my node.js. The problem is that I keep getting an error for my header in my node.js file. How can I resolve this issue?

I noticed that the image url being passed is quite long. Could that be an issue?

**Image url:**

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCAHgAoADASIAAhEBAxE..."
```

**My error is:**

```
TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "Content-Length"
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:473:3)
    at FormData.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:321:13)
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:265:7
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:251:17
    at done (C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:126:15)
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:16
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:572:34
    at C:\Users\Roger\Documents\GitHub\angular-face-recognition-app\back-end\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:105:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
```

**Front end: Angular**

Component file:

```
//captures image function
public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    //stores it into webcamImageg variable
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
    //uses fda.sendImage function to send webcamImage to api via a service
    this.fda.sendImage(this.webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl).subscribe(res => {});
}
```

Service file

```
 sendImage(imgUrl){
        console.log(imgUrl);
        const obj = {
          url: imgUrl
        };    

        return this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, obj);
    }
```

**Backend: node.js**

Route file

```
facedetAPIRoutes.route("/").post(function (req, res){
    let imageUrl = req.body.url;
    myFaceDetAPI.recognizeImg(imageUrl).then(function(result) { 
     // here is your response back
     res.json(result);
    });
});
```

Function file for api call: uses a promise

```
  //I believe problem lies  here somewhere
    this.recognizeImg = (url)=>{
        let requestString = "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com/recognize";
        let req = unirest("POST", requestString);
        let imgURL = url;   

           let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
           unirest.post(requestString)
           .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
           .attach("files", fs.createReadStream(imgURL))
           .field("album", ALBUM_NAME)
           .field("albumkey", ALBUM_KEY)
           .end(result => {
               console.log("successfully recognized image");
               resolve(result.body) // giving response back
           });
        });

       return promise;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `x-rapidapi-host` and `content-type` headers.

```
.headers({
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "",
    "useQueryString": true
})
```